# How to find specific Strings in text file in Python

Tags: python, string, text, find

```
while True:
contents = pyperclip.paste() #paste from clipboard
filepath = r"C:\Users\BOT\Desktop\DATA.txt"
with open(filepath, 'w') as f: # 'w' means write mode and we get the file object as f
                        f.write(contents)
                        f.close() #write on DATA.txt, save
                with open(filepath, 'r') as f:(edited)
```

==============
this give DATA.txt this text:

```
440    Entry Short    Short    2018-04-01 17:37:00    6479.5    
    Exit Short    Close position order    2018-04-01 17:39:00    6477    17    42.5
441    Entry Long    Long    2018-04-01 17:39:00    6477    
    Exit Long    Close position order    2018-04-01 17:41:00    6513.5    51    1861.5
442    Entry Short    Short    2018-04-01 17:41:00    6513.5    
    Exit Short    Close position order    2018-04-01 17:43:00    6503    68    714
443    Entry Long    Long    2018-04-01 17:43:00    6503    
    Exit Long    Close position order    2018-04-01 17:44:51    6517    85    1190
444    Entry Short    Short    2018-04-01 17:45:06    6518.5    
    Exit Short    Open
445    Entry Short    Short    2018-04-01 18:45:06    6525.5    
    Exit Short    Open
```

how to find strings such as last one?  "Exit Short    Open"
Output here should be 2

```
filepath = r"C:\Users\BOT\Desktop\DATA.txt"
                with open(filepath, 'w') as f: # 'w' means write mode and we get the file object as f
                        f.write(contents)
                        f.close()
                with open(filepath, 'r') as f: 
                        f.read(contents)
                        if 'Exit Short    Open' in open.f.read():
                        print('Exit Short    Open')
                        f.close()
```

not working

Comment: Can you fix the indentation to make this a runnable program? Also, post the full error, not "not working".  Was it an exception at `f.read(contents)`? Finally, consider trimming this down to the part with the problem.... the pasting and writing to the file are not necessary for the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `contents.count('Exit Short    Open')` will do the trick?
Something like that:

```
while True:
    contents = pyperclip.paste() #paste from clipboard
    filepath = r"C:\Users\BOT\Desktop\DATA.txt"
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f: # 'w' means write mode and we get the file object as f
        f.write(contents)
        # f.close() no need to close the file, "with" operator does that automatically
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        count_var = f.read().count('Exit Short    Open')
        print(count_var)
```

Comment: Good answer but I think it would help to post the entire `with` block. OP is doing a nonsense `f.read(contents)` and an unneeded `f.close()` at the end. It all needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: @tdelaney Done)

Comment: still has a bug... you read the file twice (and get an empty string the second time)